# Visual Studio C++ difference between Managed Test Project and Native Unit Test Project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to visual studio, what are some of the differences between Managed Test Project and Native Unit Test Project. Most of the unit test information available on the internet just says to make a native unit test, but what's the actual difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Visual Studio Managed is .Net and Native is pure C++.

Answer (score 1):

Having a managed C++ class, enables you to use it also in fx. C# (CSharp) .NET scope.
The memory scope is different, so if you are interfacing with .NET, then you need to use C++ managed unit test or C# unit test project